# how to remove controller name in url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My Current URL Is

http://myaliveidea.com/news/detail/hello/71/In-Ireland-hiking-for-ancient-relics-hidden-by-fog

Then i want to remove controller name 
In this URL the controller name is  == detail
and function name id = hello

So i want my URL Like this 
http://myaliveidea.com/news/hello/71/In-Ireland-hiking-for-ancient-relics-hidden-by-fog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in routes.php :

```
$route['hello/(:any)'] = "detail/hello/$1/$2";

or 

$route['hello/(:num)/(:any)'] = "detail/hello/$1/$2";
```

Answer (score 1):

in `application/config/routes.php`, rewrite the url like this:

`$route['news/hello/(:num)/(:any)'] = "news/detail/hello/$1/$2";`

I am not sure about the `news` part, if it is a subfolder in the controller folder than the above line is ok, if CI in installed in `news` subfolder, then please remove the `news` part from both side.

Make sure to accept the parameter values from the `hello` method like this:

`public function hello($id = null, $slug = null)`

Comment: my hello function is like this  function hello($id)
 {
   
  $this->load->model('news_model');
  $data['news'] = $this->news_model->readmore($id);
  
  $data['footer_recent'] = $this->news_model->get_footer_recent();
  $data['random_post'] = $this->news_model->get_randompost();
  $this->load->view('header'); 
  $this->load->view('readmore',$data);
  $this->load->view('footer');  
 }

Comment: From where the  `In-Ireland-hiking-for-ancient-relics-hidden-by-fog` part is coming?

Comment: then try this: `$route['hello/(:num)/(:any)'] = "detail/hello/$1";`, your controller should be ok.

Comment: controller name detail is not remove

Comment: I just tried this url and looks like it's working. 
http://myaliveidea.com/news/hello/71/In-Ireland-hiking-for-ancient-relics-hidden-by-fog

Comment: yes it's work but firs click on this URL http://myaliveidea.com/news/ and then click on news title "In Ireland, hiking for ancient relics hidden by fog"

Comment: You need to change those url manually from the view & remove the `detail` part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change uri path with routes, here there is [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)